# Is "thought" or "had been thinking" more common?

Tags: grammar, difference

Which one is more common?

> Sensing something amiss, I **thought** that the special relativity theory (SRT) was paradoxical until a friend of mine challenged me.

Or

> Sensing something amiss, I **had been thinking** that special relativity theory (SRT) was paradoxical until a friend of mine challenged me.

Comment: You could figure out the answer to questions like these yourself by doing a little research on the use of the PAST and PAST PERFECT tenses.

Answer (score 1):

You can just look at this Ngram viewer [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Thought%2Chad+been+thinking&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CThought%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chad%20been%20thinking%3B%2Cc0), which shows which is more commonly used.

As you can see in the link, "thought" is *a lot* more commonly used than "had been thinking".